# Why does my Swing window keep closing itself after a few seconds?

Tags: java, python, swing, user-interface, jython

Edit: In case the multiple tags are confusing, I'm working in Jython.

Here's my [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/):

```
from javax.swing import JFrame

window = JFrame('Test', 
                defaultCloseOperation = JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE,
                size = (800, 600))
window.visible = True
```

The window opens, sits there for a few seconds, and then closes. So far the only solution I've found is to add `while True: pass` to the end, which would seem to indicate that the problem is that `window` is going out of scope, so it gets cleaned up and has to close. This may in fact be another symptom of the same problem I have [encountered previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6991878/why-is-my-file-getting-closed-if-i-dont-do-anything-with-it-for-a-while).

However, I don't think wasting cycles in an infinite loop is the best solution. I guess I could make it less of an issue by sleeping for a few seconds on each loop, but I would still like to solve this *properly*.

Doing things the 'right way', creating the window on the EDT, gives exactly the same behaviour:

```
from javax.swing import JFrame, SwingUtilities
from java.lang import Runnable

class Foo(Runnable):
    def run(self):
        window = JFrame('Test', 
                        defaultCloseOperation = JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE,
                        size = (800, 600))
        window.visible = True

foo = Foo()
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(foo)
```

In previous applications this hasn't been a problem, because I've needed an infinite loop for other tasks anyway (monitoring sockets etc). However, my current application is driven purely by user input, so I don't need/want anything after I `invokeLater()`.

**Update:** Based on kingo's answer, I tried instantiating one of these:

```
class JFrameTest(JFrame):
    def addNotify(self):
        print 'In addNotify()'
        JFrame.addNotify(self)

    def removeNotify(self):
        print "In removeNotify()"
        JFrame.removeNotify(self)
```

"In addNotify()" is printed, but not "In removeNotify()", and the window behaves the same. Why would `removeNotify()` not be being called?

Also, I have tried doing `window.setVisible(True)` rather than `window.visible = True`, and that has no effect either.

Comment: Wow, still running into problems with this? Hopefully someone will give the real answer this time.

Comment: Haha yeah :/ It's a different problem this time, actually a much simpler one, but I suspect it might have the same root cause. Maybe I should log this as an issue at bugs.jython.org...

Comment: I've logged this [here](http://bugs.jython.org/issue1797), but if anyone here has a current solution/workaround that would be good too.

Comment: @Cam Jackson that isn't sscce, no idea what you are tried, not Java code, nor Swing relevant :-),

Comment: "In case the multiple tags are confusing, I'm working in Jython."

Comment: What version of jython/java are you running? With Jython 2.2.1 on Java 1.6.0_26 I can't reproduce this behavior.

Comment: @job I'm running Jython 2.5.2, Java 1.6.0_24.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following strategy to learn more about the problem:

`sun.awt.AWTAutoShutdown` is the class that prevents shutdown of the JVM if a native window peer is registered with the toolkit. Any component is registered when `addNotify()` is called on it. For a frame, this is done when you call `setVisible(true)`.

The only way a peer can get unregistered is if somebody calls `dispose()` on the peer. The only place `dispose()` is called on a peer in the JRE is from `Component#removeNotify()`.

You could override that method in your frame class and print a stack trace to see why that happens.

Comment: I have updated the question. It seems that `addNotify()` is being called, but not `removeNotify()`???